# A python linter/ static checker that can examine branches

Tags: python

I am specifically worried about:

**uninitialized values due to branch execution:** I know in Java there is `variable a might not have been initialized` when there are control flows which exist which may cause the variable not to initialize.

**return value magic:** Depending on branches, the method may return a value or inadvertently returns nothing as the branch dont reach a return.

Is there a tool that can examine whether the branches are correct? I know it needs a static typed language to do exactly that, but is there an equivalent for Python?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything for return values. In python most functions that return any type also return `None` in some cases. Of course, it would be handy to see if execution falls of the end of a function that returns non-`None` on at least one branch.

Comment: By the way, you could implement something like this using the `ast` module I think. Shouldn't be too hard, even thou it wont be trivial to get it work right.

Answer (score 0):

None of the usual suspects (PyChecker, pylint, pyflakes) handle either the "uninitialized-for-branch" case or the "return-value" case you mentioned.

I tested them all on this code:

```
x = 1

def foo():
    if False:
        y = 1
    print y     # not defined!

def bar():
    if x == 1:
        return True
    # fall off end
```

pyflakes and PyChecker report no problems, and pylint reports a bunch of stupid things (missing docstrings, doesn't like any of my variable names...).

I think both of these cases would be worth implementing in static syntax checker tools. I don't think they would be all that computationally expensive to compute or cause many if any false positives. There may be some branches that are always taken but undecidable by a reasonable syntax checker, though (e.g., if you have code that checks that at least 1000 primes exist, and if so takes the branch to define y).

Comment: Your example might give better results if the tools were developed for python3. In python2 `False` is not a keyword, so you could `False = True` somewhere, and in your `foo` `y` would always be defined. In python3 it is a keyword, so the tools could be sure that that function will raise a `NameError`.

Comment: True. I think pyflakes and most static checkers have stayed out of the business of interpreting values and expressions. That said, if you set `True` to `False`, you deserve much worse than spurious pyflakes warnings, and I don't think that's much of a concern.

Comment: Your completely right. I just pointed that out a reason why in python2 it wouldn't be 100$ safe to assert that. But in python3 it _is_ safe to say so.